# TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am basically trying to access mongodb collection from node js application. I set up the connection but while the collection I am getting this error. Here is my  .js file 
    var dbconn = require('../data/dbconnection.js');
    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

```
var hotelData = require('../data/hotel-data.json');

module.exports.hotelsGetAll = function(req, res) {

  var db = dbconn.get();

  // console.log("db", db);

  console.log('GET the hotels');
  console.log(req.query);

  var offset = 0;
  var count = 5;

  var collection = db.collection('hotels');

  if (req.query && req.query.offset) {
    offset = parseInt(req.query.offset, 10);
  }

  if (req.query && req.query.count) {
    count = parseInt(req.query.count, 10);
  }

  collection
    .find()
    .skip(offset)
    .limit(count)
    .toArray(function(err, docs) {
      console.log("Found hotels", docs.length);
      res
        .status(200)
        .json(docs);
  });

};

module.exports.hotelsGetOne = function(req, res) {
  var db = dbconn.get();
  var id = req.params.hotelId;
  var collection = db.collection('hotels');
  console.log('GET hotelId', id);

  collection
    .findOne({
      _id : ObjectId(id)
    }, function(err, doc) {
      res
        .status(200)
        .json(doc);
  });

};
```

update:  I am using MongoDB version 3.0.10 and my connection.js file is as follows

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var dburl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

var _connection = null;

var open = function() {
    MongoClient.connect(dburl, function(err , db) {
        if(err){
            console.log("DB connection failed");
            return;
        }
        _connection = db.db('meanhotels');
        console.log("DB connection open",db);

    });
};

var get = function() {
    return _connection;
};

module.exports = {
    open : open,
    get : get
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your dbconn.get() returns null. Check your DB connection string and try to connect with it thru other client (CLI tool, mongo3t)

Comment: I don't see any invocation of db.open(), so connection will remain null. Also db.open is async method and you should provide a callback to it

Comment: I have invoked db.open() in app.js so that connection will be established as soon as launching the app